# Javascript function not getting parsed by HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function

I have a question :

> My **AddCenter()** function is not being called when I click an HTML button.

**Edit :**

Thanks for all the answers, but it is still not working. So here are the changes I made :

 I moved the code to a seperate javascript file, but it is still not executing.
*It's supposed to check for some values the user enters then change my url from  [www.mywebsite.example/api/v1/im](http://www.mywebsite.example/api/v1/im) to  [www.mywebsite.example/](http://www.mywebsite.example/)*

*But intead it changes from [www.mywebsite.example/api/v1/im](http://www.mywebsite.example/api/v1/im) to [www.mywebsite.example/api/v1/im?](http://www.mywebsite.example/api/v1/im?)*
HTML file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet",
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T",
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>World Sport Center - Add Center</title>
    <style>
      .disable-select {
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="container my-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center disable-select">Add Informative Marker</h1>
        <form id="center-form" class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Sport Center Name</p>
            </blockquote>
            <input type="text" id="center-name" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Sport Center Address</p>
            </blockquote>
            <input type="text" id="center-address" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Sport Center Description</p>
            </blockquote>
            <textarea type="text" rows="2" id="center-description" class="form-control" maxlength="150"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Developper Key</p>
            </blockquote>
            <input type="text" id="dev-key" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <a href="/api/v1/add" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><-- Back</a>
          <button onclick="AddCenter" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit --></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/informative.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript file :

````js
const centers = require('../../models/Center');
const centerName = document.getElementById('center-name');
const centerAddress = document.getElementById('center-address');
const centerDescription = document.getElementById('center-description');
const key = document.getElementById('dev-key');

function CheckForURL(str)
{
  let reg = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?((\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?)', 'i')
  return reg.test(str)
}

async function AddCenter(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();

  if (centerName.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Name" field');
  else if (centerAddress.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Address" field');
  else if (centerDescription.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Description" field');
  else if (key.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Developper Key" field');
  else if (CheckForURL(centerDescription.value)) return alert('You can not put a url in the free marker "Sport Center Description" field');
  else if (key.value !== process.env['DEVELOPER_KEY'])
  {
    alert('You filled in the wrong KEY in the "Sport Center Description" field, and this window will self destruct in 10 seconds');
    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
      window.close();
    }, 10000);
    return;
  }

  centers.create({
    type: 'informative',
    name: centerName.value,
    address: centerAddress.value,
    description: centerDescription.value
  });

  if (res.status === 400)
  {
    throw Error('That sport center already exists !');
  }

  alert('Center added !');
  window.location.href = '/';
}
```<br><br>
I also made all the changes you guys told me to but the javascript function is still not getting called and functioning.
````

Comment: Your problem is the extra `)` at the end of `AddCenter`, If you also remove the `()` when you assign the button click handler, and it becomes `onclick="AddCenter"` then it will pass the event correctly. I just tested and it works fine. Try removing the typo and check the developer console for other errors.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads your variables are going to be set to null. When `AddCenter(e)` is called it's retrieving those null values set by your variables. Try moving them into the function

```
  async function AddCenter(e)
  {
    let centers = require('../models/Center');
    let centerName = document.getElementById('center-name');
    let centerAddress = document.getElementById('center-address');
    let centerDescription = document.getElementById('center-description');
    let key = document.getElementById('dev-key');
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I guess the exception with that would be... ```let centers = require('../models/Center');```

Answer (score 0):

I think by mistake you have added a closing bracket')' at the end of AddCenter() method.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet",
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T",
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>World Sport Center - Add Center</title>
    <style>
      .disable-select {
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      //let centers = require('../models/Center');
      let centerName = document.getElementById('center-name');
      let centerAddress = document.getElementById('center-address');
      let centerDescription = document.getElementById('center-description');
      let key = document.getElementById('dev-key');
      function CheckForURL(str)
      {
        let reg = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?((\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?)', 'i')
        return reg.test(str)
      }

      async function AddCenter(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        if (centerName.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Name" field');
        else if (centerAddress.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Address" field');
        else if (centerDescription.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Description" field');
        else if (key.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Developper Key" field');
        else if (CheckForURL(centerDescription.value)) return alert('You can not put a url in the free marker "Sport Center Description" field');
        else if (key.value !== process.env['DEVELOPER_KEY'])
        {
          alert('You filled in the wrong KEY in the "Sport Center Description" field, and this window will self destruct in 10 seconds');
          var timer = setInterval(function() { 
            window.close();
          }, 10000);
          return;
        }

        centers.create({
          type: 'informative',
          name: centerName.value,
          address: centerAddress.value,
          description: centerDescription.value
        });

        if (res.status === 400)
        {
          throw Error('That sport center already exists !');
        }

        alert('Center added !');
        window.location.href = '/';
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="container my-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center disable-select"> Add Informative Marker </h1>
        <form id="center-form" class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Sport Center Name</p>
            </blockquote>
            <input type="text" id="center-name" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Sport Center Address</p>
            </blockquote>
            <input type="text" id="center-address" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Sport Center Description</p>
            </blockquote>
            <textarea type="text" rows="2" id="center-description" class="form-control" maxlength="150"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p class="mb-0 disable-select">Developper Key</p>
            </blockquote>
            <input type="text" id="dev-key" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <a href="/api/v1/add" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg"><-- Back</a>
          <button onclick="AddCenter(event)" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit --></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

By the way, there are a lot of things you are doing in the wrong way.

```
  let centerName = document.getElementById('center-name');
  let centerAddress = document.getElementById('center-address');
  let centerDescription = document.getElementById('center-description');
  let key = document.getElementById('dev-key');
```

Like above all variables will be null as you have written script in the header.
The script won't find dom elements in the dom as the script written in the header runs before dom gets generated.

In your case, it will be good to have the script after dom gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a bundler, may be `AddCenter` function not accessible from the main scope, try to add `window.AddCenter = AddCenter` end of the file.

```js
const centers = require('../../models/Center');
const centerName = document.getElementById('center-name');
const centerAddress = document.getElementById('center-address');
const centerDescription = document.getElementById('center-description');
const key = document.getElementById('dev-key');

function CheckForURL(str)
{
  let reg = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?((\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?)', 'i')
  return reg.test(str)
}

async function AddCenter(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();

  if (centerName.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Name" field');
  else if (centerAddress.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Address" field');
  else if (centerDescription.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Sport Center Description" field');
  else if (key.value === '') return alert('Please fill in the "Developper Key" field');
  else if (CheckForURL(centerDescription.value)) return alert('You can not put a url in the free marker "Sport Center Description" field');
  else if (key.value !== process.env['DEVELOPER_KEY'])
  {
    alert('You filled in the wrong KEY in the "Sport Center Description" field, and this window will self destruct in 10 seconds');
    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
      window.close();
    }, 10000);
    return;
  }

  centers.create({
    type: 'informative',
    name: centerName.value,
    address: centerAddress.value,
    description: centerDescription.value
  });

  if (res.status === 400)
  {
    throw Error('That sport center already exists !');
  }

  alert('Center added !');
  window.location.href = '/';
}

// Add function to global scope
window.AddCenter = AddCenter
```